# How to share a former retrieved value between concurrent requests?

Tags: scala, stress-testing, gatling

I am currently testing a webservice with `gatling`.
Therefore I must retrieve some `accessToken` with a request to the webservice.

```
val accessToken = exec(http("access token")
  .get("""/protected/document/access.do?id=266892""")
  .headers(headers_html)
  .check(status.lessThan(400))
  .check(regex("""\"accessToken\":\"(.+?)\"""").saveAs("accessToken"))
).pause(50 milliseconds)
```

After that I do some requests to the webservice using the retrieved `accessToken`.
This works so far.

But now I want to concurrently stress-test the latter requests using the retrieved `accessToken`. The `accessToken` must only be retrieved once, but the concurrent requests afterwards should all use the same retrieved `accessToken`.

I am not that familiar with scala but I made a scala singleton and I want to store the retrieved `accessToken` in a singleton variable that can be used by the concurrent requests later.

Is this a good approach? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is `accessToken` going to be retrieved strictly once? And then subsequently used in the app for app's lifetime?

Comment: Either Futures/Promises or Actors should do the trick...

Comment: @VikasPandya yes, strictly once for the whole gatling runtime. Requesting another access token (nitpicking: for the same resource) would invalidate the former one on server side.

Answer (score 1):

How many accessToken do you want to retrieve? Only a single shared one or one per virtual user?

If the former, you can't use Gatling API for fetching it. Gatling ships AsyncHttpClient, so you can use it to fetch the accessToken and store it in the Simulation as a val.

If the latter, just use Gatling EL to inject the saved value into the other requests: "foo${accessToken}bar".

BTW, I doubt your regex is working as expected. You used triple quotes escaping, so you should have to protect your inner double quotes: """"accessToken":"(.+?)""""

Comment: I need a single shared one for all virtual users. The second approach I am currently using in conjuction with `ELFileBody` where `${accessToken}` expressions are being replaced. But this does not work across sessions/virtual users yet. 

Regex must have escaped quotations for regex parser matching the literal `"`. The escaping is for the regex parser not for scala. Try to match against `"accessToken":"blablub"`.

Comment: So like I said, you have to manually fetch the accessToken. Even URLConnection would do the job. If you do it in the Simulation body, it will be executed prior to running the simulation.

Comment: I'll try this on monday next week after my birthday and "long free weekend". Sounds like this could help. ;)

Comment: I must insist regarding what I said about double quotes escaping. This is normally required by the Scala compiler, unless you use triple double quotes like you did. See https://gist.github.com/slandelle/159f10f5c29f25cebe31

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. A real world string response looks like this `body=
{"accessToken":"2326e36f-d3f9-497d-ab25-75873d275fe5","webserviceUri":"https:\/\/deer.example.com:443\/services\/document","success":true,"idDocument":266892}`. There is a line break after `body= `. Your string does not find the access token but mine. How does this come? Is there a difference between gatling `regex()` and the one you posted?

Comment: I seriously doubt that your regex works for this string. Now, you have characters before and after your accessToken so a valid regex would be .*"accessToken":"(.+?)".*. Now, if you have further questions, please join the Gatling Google Group. SOF comments are everything but convenient.